# "Cannot access ModuleName before initialization" using import

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, circular-dependency

I'm making an API for a web application, and I'm running into a weird problem when I try to import a module. I have a folder with a bunch of models used to get data from the database, and I have a folder named "global" with various modules used all over the project.

```
/
  /api
    /models
      /Users.js
      /Trainings.js
      /TrainingsTypes.js
      /TrainingsSubtypes.js
  /global
    /Functions.js
```

Some of the models import other models to check ID, get data, etc. I made a function in `Functions.js` that also needs some of the models to work. So basically, the import dependencies look like:
[image: Dependencies]
I must admit, this is a little crappy when showed like that. But here is my problem. As long as `Functions.js` doesn't import `Users.js`, everything is fine. The API works well and there's no crash at all. But, if I import `Users.js` in `Functions.js`, I immediatly get this error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Users' before initialization
    at file:///C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/project-api/global/Functions.js:30:10
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:169:25)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:177:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

Here is the code of Functions.js (I put a comment to indicate line 30):

```js
import check from "checkers";
import Users from "../api/models/Users.js";
import Trainings from "../api/models/Trainings.js";
import TrainingsTypes from "../api/models/TrainingsTypes.js";
import TrainingsSubtypes from "../api/models/TrainingsSubtypes.js";

/*****************************************************
 * SQL Queries
 *****************************************************/

export function fieldsToUpdate(fields) {...}

const fillers = {
    "user": Users, // Line 30
    "trainer": Users,
    "type": TrainingsTypes,
    "subtype": TrainingsSubtypes
};

export async function fillIDs(db, response) {...}
```

Moreover, the import itself doesn't cause problems. If I remove `Users` from the `fillers` object, there's still no crash. I've seen that might be a cyclic dependencies issue but some says that Node can handle this. I must add that I really need all my models in `fillIDs()` so I just can't remove all the import and I didn't want to copy/paste this code in every model. There must be a solution, but I need some help.

Have you any idea how to fix this?
Thanks

**EDIT 1:**
`Users.js` import these modules:

```js
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import generatePwd from "generate-password";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import check from "checkers";
import { fieldsToUpdate, fillIDs } from "../../global/Functions.js";
import { arrayToSerialComma } from "../../global/Converters.js";
import APIResp from "../../global/APIResp.js";
import Mailer from "../../global/Mailer.js";
import Genders from "./Genders.js";
import Roles from "./Roles.js";
import Tokens from "./Tokens.js";
import { Passwords } from "../../config/config.js";
```

**EDIT 2:**
`Users.js` is exported in this way:

```js
const Users = {
    isValid,
    add,
    logIn, getAll, getById, getByEmail, hasForgotPassword, getRolesOf,
    update, updatePwd, passwordForgotten,
    delete: del,
    Trainers: {
        getById: getTrainerById,
        getAll: getAllTrainers
    }
};

export default Users;
```

Comment: what is being imported by User.js?

Comment: I'm editing my post to add them

Comment: Easiest solution would be to move the `fillers` object inside the function that is using it.

Comment: It's not ideal, but I guess I have no choice. I'll do that for now, thanks

Comment: The other option would be to arrange the import order so that the module with that object creation is executed last, but that's non-trivial, easy to break, and you haven't shown enough of your code to even tell whether it's possible.

Comment: Try exporting the `Users` in the `Users.js` file as a named export and also change the import statement in `Functions.js` file to import `Users` as a named export.

Comment: @Yousaf Switching between default and named imports won't make any difference

Comment: @Bergi In the case of circular dependencies, sometimes named exports can help [fix the issue](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/export-default-thing-vs-thing-as-default/#what-about-circular-dependencies) but as OP hasn't shared the code inside `Users.js` file, i can't say for sure. That is why i suggested OP to try it.

Comment: I tried to used named export, but it didn't seem to fix the problem @Yousaf. `User.js` is just a whole bunch of functions doing stuff with the database. All of the import are in the question (part: EDIT 1) and there's nothing more.

Comment: I also tried to rearrange the import order but couldn't find a way to make it work. And, as you said Bergi, it's pretty easy to break. I'll stick with the `fillers` object inside the function for now. If I don't find a solution tomorrow, I'll answer my own question with this solution.

Comment: @Yousaf It's not named exports that help there, it's using a declaration instead of initialising with an expression which isn't hoisted.

Comment: @Bergi right; I didn't mean to suggest that only named exports was enough to fix the issue. It was just a guess since OP didn't share how `Users` is exported and how it is defined.

Comment: I've edited my post to include the export of `Users.js`

Comment: I would say when you have circular dependancy (the functions.js in this case) that means there is a problem with your domain modelling. take a hard look at the architecture. it's a very strong indecator that refactoring is needed.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I disagree, domain models are one of the prime examples of naturally occurring circular dependencies. Sure, sometimes you can avoid them, but often that appears forced.

Comment: Ok. but domain modelling doesn't result in circular dependancy. if it is happening that means something is wrong with it. Sometimes using dependancy injection circular dependancy happens but that's always a bad case. cause most of the time even if you manage to run the app you cannot create mocks and cannot create proper unit test cases. but being said that I have not seen enough in the industry to reject your statement, but honetly whenever we had any kind of dependancy issue we took a look at how the classes are interconnected.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to partially solve my problem. I've created a file in `global` exporting all the files in this folder and did the same for `models`.

```js
// ROOT/global/global.js
export { default as APIResp } from "./APIResp.js";
export { default as SQLFunctions } from "./SQLFunctions.js";
export { default as Mailer } from "./Mailer.js";
export { default as ModuleConsole } from "./ModuleConsole.js";

// ROOT/api/models/models.js
export { default as Users } from "./Users.js";
export { default as Genders } from "./Genders.js";
export { default as Roles } from "./Roles.js";
export { default as Tokens } from "./Tokens.js";
export { default as Trainings } from "./Trainings.js";
export { default as TrainingsTypes } from "./TrainingsTypes.js";
export { default as TrainingsSubtypes } from "./TrainingsSubtypes.js";
```

I also removed some functions that was needed in both the front-end and back-end and moved them to an external module. I used [madge](https://github.com/pahen/madge) to generate a dependency graph.

[image: Dependencies graph]

As we can see, it's not perfect yet. All the models files are actually in a big circular dependency but it's much cleaner than before and there are no more crashes.
This may have an impact on performance, and I have to be careful with that.

I mark this answer as correct for now, I may change it if someone else or I found something.

Comment: Thank you for your advice about `madge`, it has save me the day! :-D